# How does pixel shading work for ambient occlusion volumes?

Tags: graphics, rendering, gpu, pixel-shader

I'm trying to understand the ambient occlusion technique described [here](http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/papers/AOVHPG10/AOV-tr.pdf), but I've trouble comprehending what exactly is the pixel shader doing.

Is the pixel shader invoked on points that belong to the surfaces of occlusion volumes? Can  anyone explain on a simple scene (like a cube corner seen from inside) how pixels get their AO values?

(Crossposted from [game stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/46510/how-does-pixel-shading-work-for-ambient-occlusion-volumes))

Answer (score 0):

Basically Pixel Shader is responsible for reflecting the light in a object depending on what angle the poligons is facing the virtual light source. in that case AO is made possible by the help of pixel shader emulating the light and its amount in every single texture. Note: Pixel Shading is real time so if the object or the viewing point moves, the light also move and make a realistic textures.